# Can't locate element by id in scala-js-dom

Tags: scala, dom, scala.js

I'm trying to write text to an element in the DOM:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Scala.js Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Include Scala.js compiled code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.13/hello-world-fastopt/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the element is null:

```scala
package hello

import org.scalajs.dom

object TutorialApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(dom.document.getElementById("output")) // null
    dom.document.onload = (e) => {
      println(dom.document.getElementById("output")) // null
    }
  }
}
```

What's needed to do to get to the element with id "output"?

**Edit**: Answers to questions:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    println("innerHTML: " + dom.document.body.innerHTML)
    dom.document.onload = (e) => {
      println("onload") // Doesn't get called
    }
}
```

1. Locally, compiling with `sbt fastOptJS`. The end result line is:

`[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Dec 13, 2020 4:30:36 PM`

2. The HTML is as is rendered in the HTML page (`hello-world-template/index-dev.html`) (by viewing source), verbatim. It's printing "Initial text" inside the `<DIV>`.
3. Printing the body's innerHTML in main() results in TypeError (see code comment). The onload() in the code seems to not get called at all, as a println() call inside of it doesn't print.
4. Yes, it printed `null` in the browser console.

Comment: Use `#output` instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You mean accessing the element by `dom.document.getElementById("#output")`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: This seems to have produced no effect:
```javascript
> document.getElementById("output")
> <div id="output"></div>
```

```scala
println(dom.document.getElementById("#output")) // null
```

Comment: The original syntax seems to be correct. Are you running this locally with `fastOptJS::webpack`, or is there more going on? Are you sure the HTML you showed is actually used when you run the code? Add some text inside your div to make sure that you're actually seeing it. Add `println(dom.document.body.innerHtml)` inside `onload`, and see what that says. It should print out your div. And to be extra clear, when you say "null" it did in fact print "null", not failed to print out anything, right?

Comment: @Nikita I've added answers to your questions to my question.

Comment: Oh hey @PedroSobota one thing I didn't notice earlier, I'm not sure if you can assign `document.onload` this way, might not be supported by all browsers. Try this instead: `dom.window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ev => println(dom.document.getElementById("output")))` If still no luck, try asking / linking to this in the scala-js gitter room if you haven't yet.

Comment: @Nikita That was it, you killed it :) Would you be so kind as to post your text as an answer? Thank you,

Comment: Phew, sorry didn't notice it the first time, such an obvious thing. Will post actual answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(dom.document.getElementById("output")) // null
    dom.document.onload = (e) => {
      println(dom.document.getElementById("output")) // null
    }
  }
```

The first `println` prints null because at this point the browser hasn't finished parsing HTML / instantiating the DOM (simplifying a bit...). The browser reads the HTML top to bottom and builds up the DOM tree as it goes, and when it sees your script tag, it "blocks", i.e. downloads and executes the script first before reading the rest of the DOM. That's when your `main` runs, and why the `output` div could not be found at this stage – the browser didn't get to it yet.

To solve this, you *could* move your script tag to be below the `<body>` tag in your HTML, so that the script would be downloaded and executed **after** the document is all parsed and the DOM all initialized.

But a nicer solution is to delay DOM access in the script until the browser fires an event indicating it's safe to do that. That's what you're trying to achieve by assigning `dom.document.onload`, but this is kinda "old style" in JS world, and is not universally supported by all browsers (specifically `dom.document.onload` I mean, I think assigning `dom.window.onload` might work just fine).

Ultimately it's best to use modern syntax for this:

```scala
dom.window.addEventListener("load", ev => {
  println(dom.document.getElementById("output"))
})
```

You can also use the "DOMContentLoaded" event instead of "load", they serve the same purpose, but have slightly different timing related to waiting for resources like images. Does not matter in your case though. Check MDN for details if curious.

Comment: This is a great answer. I didn't know `dom.document.onload` was mapped 1:1 to the DOM equivalent in Scalajs (it could be a browser-agnostic API instead), but it's always nice to know. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, as a rule, almost everything in the `scala-js-dom` package is mapped 1:1 to the real JS DOM (you can see it in the source code of `scala-js-dom`, where is says `js.native` on all the classes, methods and vars / vals) so it's easy to look for answers in JS world and then just do pretty much the same thing in Scala.js